# Silently use Java Robot to Screenshot

Tags: java, windows, macos, screenshot, awtrobot

I have to made a Java application that capture screen every second
(for example).

But this application have to run silently like if we use (javaw for
windows user).

#### The problem is that Robot usage create a frame and the menu bar of application.

[image]

**So the main question is :**

*How I can proceed to screen silently ?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just using : `apple.awt.UIElement=true` on vm options for Apple